# Python PyQt4 progressbar Freezing GUI

Tags: python, progress-bar, pyqt4, freeze

the following code counts a bunch of PyQt4 progressbar's up tp 99%, I would like for my GUI **NOT** to freeze as they count up to 99%. I would LOVE to do this **without custom classes or functions** if it is possible.
I know it is good to use classes but for this tiny snippet of code I don't want to create a class.
From what I've read there may be a update() function that could accomplish this ... please advise If I'm on the right track

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QtGui.QWidget()
widget.resize(400, 200)
widget.setWindowTitle('simple')
widget.show()

shift = 0
cntControl = 5
barra = [0] * cntControl
for i in range(cntControl):
    shift = shift + 10
    barra[i] = QtGui.QProgressBar(widget)
    barra[i].show()
    barra[i].setMinimum(0)
    barra[i].setMaximum(10000)
    barra[i].setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, shift, 200, 10))


for a in range(10000):
    for i in range(cntControl):
        barra[i].setValue(a)



sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your for loop with:

```
while True:
    for a in range(10000):
        time.sleep(0.0001)
        for i in range(cntControl):
            barra[i].setValue(a)
```

if works for me.
The while loop continues endlessly moving the bar. If you are looking only to clean the bar after it reaches the end you should use reset:

> ```
> PySide.QtGui.QProgressBar.reset()
> Reset the progress bar. The progress bar “rewinds” and shows no
> progress
> ```

**Update after OP comments:** If you want your gui to be responsive when entering a long loop or other operation you should use either python [thread module](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#module-thread) or [QThreads](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qthread.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. My question was actually asking ... why does my Main Window FREEZE while the progressbars are moving ... it only unfreezes once all progressbars have finished

Comment: I've been trying to run each progressbar in an individual thread and am getting the following error: ....
QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread. .... and ...
QObject::startTimer: timers cannot be started from another thread ... I will research Qthreads

Comment: @Rhys: it is difficult to know what happens to your threads without actual code, but the answer to your initial question stands: use threads.  You should post your new code and the exception traceback but this would be another question.

Comment: QThreads worked perfectly thanks. Note to anyone reading ... you will need to learn signals and emits if you plan to try Qthreads

Answer (score 0):

I really could not get threads to work at all ... I could post my thread attempt which looks flawless to my (now tired) eyes ...

I have however been able to tweek http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/widgets/ 's progressbar example and came out with the following code ... which solves the problem of freezing in the GUI:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('ProgressBar')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)

        self.pbar = [0] * 3
        self.timer = [0] * 3
        self.step = [0] * 3
        self.shift = 0
        for i in range(3):
            self.shift = self.shift + 30
            self.pbar[i] = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
            self.pbar[i].setGeometry(30, self.shift, 200, 25)

            self.timer[i] = QtCore.QBasicTimer()
            self.step[i] = 0
            self.timer[i].start(100, self)


    def timerEvent(self, event):
        for i in range(3):
            if self.step[i] >= 100:
                self.timer[i].stop()
                return
            self.step[i] = self.step[i] + 1
            self.pbar[i].setValue(self.step[i])




app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) ex
= Example() ex.show() app.exec_()
```

I have NO IDEA why it works which is probably not a good thing. I'm guessing it might have something to do with `super(Example, self).__init__()` and the custom timer pyqt4 uses. I was really hoping to do this without functions or classes, but not sure that is possible. If you think it is, feel free to post!